How does SEM handle response biases?
Structural equation modeling (SEM) can help decompose errors and identify response biases at both individual and aggregate levels (Rosenman et al., 2011).
How does SEM handle response biases?
Rosenman, R., Tennekoon, V., & Hill, L. G. (2011). Measuring bias in self-reported data. International Journal of Behavioural and Healthcare Research, 2(4), 320-332.

From the paper you cite: "In recent years, researchers have applied structural equation modelling (SEM) to the problem of decomposing error in order to identify response shift bias (Oort, 2005; Oort et al., 2005)" Did you follow those references?
